# Java and SQLite: avoid database locking errors

Tags: java, database, multithreading, sqlite

### Scenario:

I am trying to write a program that can read and write to an SQLite database. The application can be opened by multiple computers connected by a network/shared folder with the db file (so that multiple people can add/read the data at once).

### Problem:

Whenever I try to edit the database with more than 1 window open, the 'database is locked' error inevitably comes up (they can simultaneously read it fine). I am closing every resultSet as soon as possible but the connection is kept open the whole time.

So essentially, I would like to know when the database is locked/unlocked, and if it is possible to only lock the database when updating and unlock it at other times.

My code to connect to the database is:

```
    try {
        //Create and/or connect to the database
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        //c is a global Connection variable
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbLocation);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) { 
        //print the error message if there is an exception
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The connection is maintained throughout the time the application is run and closed `c.close();` when the application interface is closed

Thanks :)

Comment: Consider using H2 - it's also file databse, but handles such problems much better

Comment: Do you have a connection pool or something?? database locked occurs when you try to do two incompatible things with a database at the same time from the same database connection.

Comment: At the moment, I'm running the application twice on one computer and both are updating/reading the same database file location. Or trying to - whenever I try to update or change something, a locking error occurs. Since they are separate instances, I believe they should be using separate connections.

Comment: running application twice? does it imply on your connections are created on session basis?? or is it static?? how do you manage your connections ? can you put some code in your question regarding how you create connection and how you access the connection??

Comment: You could always consult [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Comment: And running the same application twice will result in interference.  Keep in mind that if you do two updates simultaneously you could end up with corruption, were it not prevented with some sort of lock.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, but I don't understand how that process is run from java. It seems like the database is always locked even when no result sets are open. Also, neither instance can write to the database because it is locked. I don't understand which application it is locked to, though. I would like the database to be locked when updating/inserting/deleting, but unlocked at other times.

Comment: I've changed to using H2, as Konstantin suggested, and the mixed mode is working amazingly :)